# Markov Processes: $P_x$ and $E_x$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, markov-process, conditional-expectation

In the study of Markov processes, one usually introduces the measures $P_{\pi}$ on the path space of the process where $\pi$ is an initial distribution of the process $X$ i.e $\pi=\mathcal L(X_0)$. The expectation w.r.t to this measure is denoted $E_{\pi}$. In the case $\pi=\delta_x$ one writes $P_x$ and $E_x$. Here and there I have seen remarks regarding the relationship between $P_x$ and $P(\cdot\mid X_0=x)$. It seems they should be versions of each other. Is this true, i.e $$P_x[X\in A]\overset{?}{\overset{\text{a.s}}{=}}P[X\in A\mid X_0=x]$$
If so, is it supposed to be obvious by definition, or can it be somehow formally derived? It seems that it's just "obvious by definition" by I don't want to be careless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the definition (and a reason why the "a.s." above the equal sign is absurd).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why does it make the "a.s" absurd though? Isn't equality between conditional probabilities usually taken as their a.s equality as random variables?

Comment: You are (again) confusing conditional probabilities conditionally on a sigma-algebra (the result is a random variable) and conditionally on an event of positive probability (the result is a number).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for making it explicit; got it now.

Comment: Breiman's Probability (chapter 7.1 problem 1.a):
"Show that $p^{(n)}(A\mid x)$ equals $P_x(X_n\in A)$ hence is a *version* of $P(X_n\in A\mid X_0=x)$."
Also, isn't conditioning by an event $A$ formally defined as conditioning on the $\sigma$-Algebra $\left\{ \emptyset ,A,A^c,\Omega \right\}$? If so, it seems that all conditional probabilities are random variables, and ones conditioned on trivial $\sigma$-algebras are just a.s constant.
Could you clarify?

Comment: *Conditioning by an event is formally defined as conditioning on*... the event, thus, for every $B$, $P(B|A)=P(B\cap A)/P(A)$. To condition on the sigma-algebra $\sigma(A)$, use the notation $P(B|\sigma(A))$, which is the random variable $P(B|A)\mathbf 1_A+P(B|A^c)\mathbf 1_{A^c}$.